# PHP - Update Apache Version Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache2

Recently after vulnerability assessment and penetration testing we are asked to upgrade our apache ubuntu version. Below is the screenshot attached. The solution they proposed is Update version of Apache to fix these vulnerabilities

[image: vulnerability Testing]

PHP info details

```
PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4
Apache Version  Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
```

Being a newbie, I have below questions

1. What is the correct approach to upgrade Apache ?
2. If I do it, will this also upgrade my PHP version ?

P.S. The site is running `joomla` and some core php applications

Comment: See this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeApacheHTTPServer

Comment: How about creating VM and perform some operations on that ? and If everything goes ok do the same steps on your live server

Comment: @waki, the screenshot is sent by `vulnerability assessment and penetration testing` team and they suggested to upgrade apache version.
@juned, what kind of operations. I just need to know the dependency of apache upgrade on php application and also the method to upgrade.

Comment: standard command is to upgrade any package is `apt-get upgrade package-name` so it will upgrade dependent package as well. Here operation refers the commands which you execute to upgrade your apache

Comment: What `vulnerability assessment and penetration testing` you referring here, that URL(/etc/passwd) ?

Comment: Vulnerability Desc: `It is possible to craft a malformed chunk size as part of chunked request that enalbes unlimited amount of data to be streamed to server. This enables a DOS attack`

Comment: @juned, also looking at the PHP and Apache versions, do you think it should be upgraded really ?

Comment: Tell your pentest team to come back with a better screenshot. The current one is meaningless, unless they're complaining about the server information shown, which is easily obtained even if hidden.